# GATES de laravel. Restringir rutas por rol

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

El modelo es un usuario tiene muchos roles y un rol tiene muchos usuarios

Modelo usuarios

```
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Rol','usuarios_roles','idusuario','idrol');
    }
```

modelo roles

```
 public function usuarios()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','usuarios_roles','idusuario','idrol');
    }
```

He visto la documentacion pero esos ejemplos no me funcionan. Lo que necesito es restringir una ruta por rol. Ejemplo solo los usuarios con rol **ver** pueden acceder a la ruta '**usuarios-inicio**'. El rol **create** puede acceder a la ruta **usuarios-crearNuevo**. Esto donde se define? en las rutas (lo dudo), en policies creando el archivo? o en authServicePrivider. Estoy muy confundido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente pude dar con la respuesta. Usé middleware. me gusto más y fue más sencillo de entender para mi.

Creacion del middleware.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckRole
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {

        if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

registrarlo en el kernel ubicado en http/kernel. En la seccion routeMiddleware

```
'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class,
```

Notese que **role** es el alias que voy a utilizar para referirme al middleware.

Aplico el filtro en la ruta. Archivo en routes/web.php

```
Route::get('usuarios', 'UsuarioController@index')->middleware('role:ver;insertar;admin');
```

Notese que solo los usuarios con rol **ver,insertar,admin** pueden ver esa ruta. Estan separados por punto y coma ya que separados por coma no me funcionaba.

En el modelo user tengo

```
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Rol','usuarios_roles','idusuario','idrol');
    }
```

// hasRole verifica si el usuario tiene un rol en especifico en una lista de roles o solo uno. rolesArray .

```
        public function hasRole(string $roleSlug)
        {


             $roles = $roleSlug;
             $rolesArray = explode(';',$roles);  
             $roles = $this->roles()->whereIn('nombre', $rolesArray)->count() > 0;
             return $roles;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer de varias formas, pero considero que la forma más sencilla es en el Request, que va atado al controlador respectivo de la ruta, utilizando el método `authorize()` y apoyándose en las policies.

A continuación te muestro (más o menos) como está implementado esto en un proyecto real en producción.

Policy:

```
<?php

namespace app\Policies;

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use app\Models\{Group, User};

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    protected $roles = [Group::ADMIN_CODE, Group::SUPER_ADMIN_CODE];

    /**
     * Determine if the given user can manage others.
     *
     * @param  User $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function manage(User $user)
    {
        return $user->hasRole($this->roles);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Request:

```
<?php

namespace app\Http\Requests\User;

use app\Http\Requests\Request;

class ManageRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return $this->user()->can('manage-users');
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Modelo User:

Aquí defines el método hasRole() de la forma que desees implementarlo.

```
/**
 * Check if current user belongs to the given Group.
 *
 * @param  string|array
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function hasRole($roles)
{
    if (!is_array($roles)) {
        $roles = [$roles];
    }

    $userGroupCodes = $this->groups->pluck('code');

    return $userGroupCodes->intersect($roles)->count() > 0;
}
```

Como lo puedes apreciar en el código, en este caso hay un modelo Group, que puede funcionar muy similar a tu modelo Rol.

Comment: mmm. Lo que no entiendo es como ajustar para que un usuario con el rol "Create" no pueda ver la vista create de categorias. Soy nuevo en el tema de gates asi que por ahora no te entiendo mucho eso

Comment: Tienes alguna referencia que me pueda ayudar? sobre permisos de ruta por roles usando gates. para entender mejor eso

Comment: Y pienso yo no sería más fácil crear un/varios middleware   https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

Comment: Como te decía, realmente hay muchas firmas de hacerlo, en este proyecto consideramos que era más fácil así, pero dependiendo el enfoque puede ser más fácil con middleware, puede que sea más coherente teniendo en cuenta que el middleware puede venir "antes" del request.

Comment: Me parecio mas sencillo middleware. Con ese logre dar la solucion que queria.